# How to modify the implementation of the map function in the Array class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to modify the implementation of map() in the Array class such that it only affects certain indices of the array?

Example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.map(2..4) { |x| x*2 }
```

Now, `a = [1, 2, 6, 8, 10]` since the map function was only used on indices 2 and 3.

Comment: What happened to index 4?

Comment: Let r = `2..4`. Then you need to write `a.map.with_index { |n,i| r.cover?(i) ? 2*n : n } #=> [1, 4, 6, 8, 10]`. That returns a new array and leaves `a` unchanged. If you wish to modify `a` use `map!` rather than `map`. See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm still very new to Ruby and forgot that ".." is inclusive. I have fixed it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (but *really* shouldn't) do this:

```rb
Array.class_eval do
  def map(range = nil)
    return super() if range.nil?
    return self[range].map unless block_given?

    self[range].map { |x| yield x }
  end
end

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map(2..4) { |x| x * 2 }
# => [6, 8, 10]
```

Ruby already has a MUCH more normal/nice/better way of "select only certain indices", with `arr[2..4]`:

```rb
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr[2..4].map { |x| x * 2 }
# => [6, 8, 10]
```

I've avoided mutation above, but if you *must* have that as well, you can do something similar to the above, just with `map!` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. I would have just used the Ruby implementation of what I was talking about, but my professor ONLY wants us to modify the Array class. I have been trying to solve this problem for a week but it seems my Ruby fundamentals are still not that great. Thank you for providing your insight, I really appreciate it.